# Change the order of Pivot tables in same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, msgbox

I have multiple pivot tables on one same worksheet (from left to right : PvtTable 1, Pvttable 2, Pvttable3). I have introduced a iterator (i) to call them one after the other (msgbox their name). However, when i run the macro, the names are in an illogical order : they don't display pvttable1 then 2 then 3 nor backwards (3,2,1). It displays pvttable2, pvttable1, pvttable3. Is there a tool that wold help me initiate and tell VBA which one to call first ? What is this order based on ?
Simple piece of code I use that returns a weird order :

```
For i = 1 to 3 
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.PivotTables(i).Name
Next i
```

*my pivot tables have changing string names btw, the names mentioned are just examples to help make understand they don't appear in order

Thanks everyone, hope it was clear!

Comment: *What is this order based on ?* As far as I know, the order is determined by which Pivot Table was first created in the file.

Comment: You cannot change the order once the pivot tables are created. But you can call them by their names like `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pvttable" & i)`, or you can read all the names in a dictionary first and then sort the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

If your Pivot Tables names don't follow a pattern, you can create an Array unidimensional and use it to call them. Something like this should be helpful

```
Sub test()
Dim MyPivotTables As Variant
Dim i As Long

MyPivotTables = Array("", "PvtTable 1", "Pvttable 2", "Pvttable3")

For i = 1 To UBound(MyPivotTables) Step 1 'we omit index 0, so i= 1,2,3 ---> first table, second table and so on
    MsgBox "Index: " & i & vbCrLf & "Pivot Table: " & MyPivotTables(i)
Next i

Erase MyPivotTables

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much, however the names in my question were to make understand that the pivottables don't show in order, in my folder, i don't have names with an incrementing variable, but rather only string names that may change, and so that's why i'm struggling with the order... but thanks for your help !!

Comment: @Ali That's the point of my code. You don't need names with an incrementing variable, you just need to type them in the line `MyPivotTables = Array("", "PvtTable 1", "Pvttable 2", "Pvttable3")` in the order you want. You just need the string names

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I have put my pvttable names in an array however then to call each pvttable i use an iterator "i". The problem is that apparently pivottables are called by the order of creation so I can't use the i to name the pvttable ... unless i enter the names in the array in the specific order of which the pvttables were created, but then i run the risk of someone deleting and redoing a pvttable and that order will thus be changed. I am sorry I hope it is understandable. In any case your help is ever so appreciated ! THanks !!!